# Session variable in java

Tags: java, session, global-variables

I am newbie in Java that's why my question could sound strange and stupid. But anyway, I have several forms (classes that extend JFrame). What I want is to have a variable that is accessible for reading and for writing in all the forms. When I create an interface and implement it in my forms all the variables of the interface are accessible in the forms but only for reading, I can not assign new value for them.

Question: Is it possible to do that in java at all? If yes then how?

Comment: Without more info my glass ball says add a setXXX method on the interface

Comment: @vickirk. Could you please post as a new answer with more detailed information (I highly appreciate if you could give brief code also) about your opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Interfaces don't have variables, they only have `final` members - i.e. constants. You could replace the interface with a class and then you'll have access to the class members of interest.

Comment: but my classes extend JFrame and couldn't extend the second class you are telling about, if I have gotten you right.

Comment: Use a delegate and simply call the delegate methods from the class to that.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want either a singleton or a class with a bunch of static properties.

The main thing to keep in mind is that if you have multiple threads accessing the "global" properties is that the access needs to be synchronized.

Answer (score 0):

In Java Interfaces only have `final` members. And by that it means that those members are final. Most probably you can't extend a class since your Form classes are extending JFrame. The an option to use here is to have an intermediate inheritance class. Look below for example.

```
class intermediateClass extends JFrame{
 //some code if any

 String name;
 //Getter/Setter
}

class yourForm extends intermediateClass{
 public yourForm(){
  setName("Ddd");
  System.out.println(getName());
 }
}
```

But I won't personally recommend it. I would rather suggest you use a different class - Specially your class with the Main method to hold these variables. For example I use a class called Runner to execute Java applications-

```
class Runner{
 String name;
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  setName("Dchan");
  System.out.println(getName());
 }
 //getter/setter
}
```

Hope this helps